# SharePoint 2010 - Restore default "Style Resource Readers" permissions group

Tags: permissions, groups

What tasks are necessary to restore the default "Style Resource Readers" permission group?
My problem is that a Sitecolletion Administrator erased this default group.

> Members of this group are given Read permission to the Master Page
>   Gallery and Restricted Read permission to the Style Library. By
>   default, all authenticated users are a member of this group.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262690.aspx#section1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did he delete the group entirely or just remove the group's permission?

If the group's permission was removed, they can be readded to those libraries with the specified permissions.

If the group was deleted, a new "All Users" group can be created.  When you go to add users, there's a link to include all authentcated users.  Click that link and click OK.  Then add this group to the library permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have created a new "All User" group and set the permissons. But when I want to open the site I get a "Access denied" message. It is possible that this is a group, that can not so easy restored?